# Sequence contains more than one element c# Entity Seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

Trying to seed Countries from CSV Entity but getting this error when ever i run Update-Database. If i delete the table and run Update-Database then the error doesn't show up but if i run Update-Database again.

CSV file

```
Name,
China,
India,
United States,
Indonesia,
Brazil,
Pakistan,
United Kingdom,
Bangladesh,
Russia,
Japan,
Mexico,
Philippines,
Vietnam,
Ethiopia,
Egypt,
Germany,
Iran,
Turkey,
Democratic Republic of the Congo,
Thailand,
France,
Italy,
Burma,
South Africa,
South Korea,
Colombia,
Spain,
Ukraine,
```

My Country Model

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Country : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}



using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Domain
{
    public class BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Seed

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

const string country = "Service.Migrations.Seed.countries.csv";
            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(country))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
                    csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
                    var countries = csvReader.GetRecords<Country>().ToArray();
                }
            }
```

Error

```
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, Expression`1 identifierExpression, TEntity[] entities)
   at Service.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(HotelContext context) in C:\Hotel+\Service\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 55
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains more than one element
```

Comment: Generally when you used `SingleOrDefault` and if that result contains more then 1 result in that case you get this error.

Comment: @PranavPatel as you can see the csv fields are all unique. what do suggest

Comment: can you please show me your update code ? and which csvReader you have used ?

Comment: How are your Id fields populated? Perhaps this is triggering the error?

Comment: @PranavPatel I am using CsvHelper

Comment: @Hintham the Id is Auto Increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
const string country = "Service.Migrations.Seed.countries.csv";
            using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(country))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
                    csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
                    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
                    var countries = csvReader.GetRecords<Country>().ToArray();
                    foreach (var c in countries)
                    {
                        var check = context.Countries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == c.Name);
                        if (check == null)
                        {
                            context.Countries.Add(c);
                            context.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ID is auto-increment so if you do not check if the current **Country Name** is already in your database, EF will create a new entry with a new ID...

You have two solutions to avoid this :

**Solution 1 :**

Loop inside the **Countries** in your database and check if the name already exist. If that the case do not add it again.

**Solution 2 :**

Set the **Country Name** as unique like this :

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Country : BaseModel
    {
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception when you will try to add a name that already exit in your database. You can manage the error with a **try-catch** and log the exception for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion below is my solution. :)